# Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully during deployment in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm encountering an error during the deployment of my Firebase functions. The error message I'm receiving is:

`"Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error."`

I have reviewed my code and ensured that there are no syntax errors. However, the error persists. I have also checked the necessary API requirements and they are enabled.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Please find below the relevant code snippet:

```
export const readTarjeta = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const imageBucket = `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`;
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

    const [textDetection] = await client.textDetection(imageBucket);
    const [annotation] = textDetection.textAnnotations;
    const text = annotation ? annotation.description : "";
    logger.log(text);

   const re = /(.*)\//;
   const uid = re.exec(object.name)[1];

  const regexArray = [
    // /(?<=PROPIETARIO?)\s*(.*)\n/,
    /\bJ[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\b/gm,
    /(?<=MODELO)\s*(.*)\n/,
    /[a-zA-Z0-9]{17}$\n/gm,
];

let regExpSalto = /propietario:\s*\n/i;

 let propietario;
 let placasJ;
 let marcaJ;
 let anio;
 let modeloJ;
 let motorJ;
 let nivJ;
 
    if(regExpSalto.test(text)){
        let regExpBajo = /propietario:\s*\n\s*((\w+\s){3,4})\s+/i;
        if(regExpBajo.test(text)){
            let matches2 = text.match(regExpBajo);
            if(matches2){
                  propietario = matches2[1];
            }
        }else{

            let a = "Propietario:\\s+"
            let b = "(( +\\w+){3,5}\\s*\\n)"
            let saltoLinea = ".+\\s+"
            let saltoLinea2 = "";
            
            
            let tes = "";
            let testeo = new RegExp();
            let condicion;

            let i = 0;

            while(!condicion && i <= 7){
                saltoLinea2 += saltoLinea;

                tes = a+saltoLinea2+b;
                testeo = RegExp(tes,"i")
                condicion = testeo.test(text)
                
                let matches = text.match(testeo);

                    if(matches){
                         propietario = matches[1];
                        
                    }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }else{
        let regExp = /PROPIETARIO:\s*([^\n\r]+)/;
        let matches = text.match(regExp);
        if(matches){
              propietario = matches[1];
              
        }else{
            propietario = "no se encontro el nombre del propietario"
        }
    }

    let regExpModelo = /\s+(\d{4})\n/;
    let matchesModelo = text.match(regExpModelo);
    if (matchesModelo) {
        anio = matchesModelo[1];
    } else {
        anio = "No se encontró el modelo del vehiculo";
    }

    let regExpPlacas = /\s(\w{3}\d{3,4})\n/;
    let matchesPlacas = text.match(regExpPlacas);
    if (matchesPlacas) {
        placasJ = matchesPlacas[1];
    } else {
        placasJ = "No se encontraron las placas del vehículo";
    }

        marcaJ = todasLasMarcas.find((marca) => {
          const regexMarca = new RegExp(`^\\s*\\b${marca}\\b`, 'im');
            return regexMarca.test(text);
          });
          
          if (!marcaJ) {
            marcaJ = "No se encontró la marca";
          }
          
        const lineas = text.split('\n').slice(7); 

        modeloJ = todosLosModelos.find((modelo) => {
            const regexModelo = new RegExp(`^\\s*\\b${modelo}\\b`, 'im');
            return lineas.some((linea) => regexModelo.test(linea));
          });
        
          if (!modeloJ) {
            modeloJ = "No se encontró el modelo";
          }



            const regexMotor = /[NUM]*[No.]*\s*MOTOR:\s*([\w-]{5,20})/i;
            const matchMotor = text.match(regexMotor);

            if (matchMotor) {
                const numeroMotor = matchMotor[1];
                motorJ = numeroMotor;
            } else {
                motorJ = "No se encontró el número de motor en el texto";
            }

            let regexpNiv = /\b[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{17}\b/i; //Omite O, Q y I
            let matchesNiv = text.match(regexpNiv);
            if (matchesNiv) {
                nivJ = matchesNiv[0];
                
            } else {
                nivJ="No se encontraron coincidencias para el NIV";
            }

const fields = {
  // owner: "",
  // placas: "",
  // modelo: "",
  // serie: "",
};

for (let i = 0; i < regexArray.length; i++) {
  const regex = regexArray[i];
  const match = text.match(regex);
  if (match) {
      const fieldName = Object.keys(fields)[i];
      fields[fieldName] = match[0]?.trim()?.replace(/^(\w+:)\s*/, '');
  }
}
const car ={
  owner: propietario,
  placas: placasJ,
  serie: nivJ, // Use serie or modelo if serie is not found
  year: anio,
  brand: marcaJ,
  model: modeloJ,
  motor: motorJ,
  isConfirmed: false,
  userUid:uid,
  imageBucket
}

  logger.log(car)

  admin.firestore().collection("Cars").add(car);
  logger.log(car);
})
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!

I have double-checked my code for any syntax errors or runtime issues, but couldn't find any. Is there any other possible cause for this error? How can I resolve it and successfully deploy my Firebase Functions?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting the same error for a project I'm working on. Really having a hard time figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 11):

So the error could be just about anything.
For example you could be having a permissioning error based on your rules.

There is a way to get the exact error message out and that is by using the `--debug` parameter when deploying.

The full command to use is:

```
firebase deploy --only functions --debug
```

Using this you can hopefully get out the exact problem which should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the error this way:

1. Run the `firebase emulators:start' command
2. When functions fails to start, a new file called `firebase-debug.log` will be created at the root of your project
3. Open the `firebase-debug.log` file and scroll down to the bottom